# learning Data harvesting

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, webharvest, data-harvest

I want to build a website that will harvest data from:
*facebook status of my friends
*other website

Unfortenatly, I don't know how to harvest data.
Can someone recommend of a book\tutorial ? How to approch this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is [Web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Unfortunately, copying data from Facebook and other websites and re-publishing it has a number of legal and ethical issues, which are probably more significant than the technical hurdles.

If you intend to use C# (I'm guessing from your tag), the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library will be useful.

Comment: I tried using js instead of c#.